# gradle subproject task progect dir

Tags: gradle, subproject

I have a subproject task in a multi project like this

```
task genJaxb {
    ext.sourcesDir = "/${rootProject.projectDir}/src/resources/xjc" ...
```

The project itself compiles fine, however when I compile the project from the parent project the ${rootProject.projectDir} is resolved to the parent project path. And I get errors. When I compile the project from parent I want rootProject.projectDir to be resolved to the sub project directory.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried just `"$projectDir"`?

Comment: This works , thank you

Answer (score 1):

As ReGa mentioned, it works fine, also using relative paths also works